Convert encoding from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8 in PHP project
I have an old PHP project written in PHP 5.2, and am updating it to PHP 8.2
It extracts data from a SQL Server database, and on specific button presses it fills out this data into existing Excel templates.
Since PHPExcel does not exist any more I have used composer to replace it with phpspreadsheet across my project. The project is using UTF-8 for encoding (Header and meta included in my PHP and HTML), and also when connecting to the database.
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8

I have also changed the default charset = UTF-8 in my php.ini file
On my webpage all the German umlauts are showing without any problem, but the Excel files are not being filled out properly. It seems there is an encoding mismatch somewhere. In my Excel file the word Prüfung"shows like this: prÃ¼fung
The collation of my SQL Server database is Latin1_General_CI_AS.
Any ideas? I am expecting the German umlaut characters to be displayed and printed correctly.

Please provide a [mre] of your issue including relevant code and sample data. We can't fix descriptions alone. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your question. Thanks.

Are you writing to .xlsx Excel files? If you're writing to .csv files then it's probably an Excel issue as it has numerous problems dealing with UTF-8 encoded text files. Start by making sure that your .csv files include a BOM.

I also inherited 2 projects with PHPexcel. After a short analysis, I decided to adapt PHPexcel to PHP8 so that both projects work without any problems again: https://github.com/Wiimm/PHPExcel

I am writing to .xlsx files. So are you using phpspreadsheet now?  what else did you change to ensure they work, in addition to what I mentioned above?

@Butch82 Wimm clearly stated that they are using an adapted version of phpexcel, instead of switching to phpspreadsheet. Not sure how that was unclear from the comment

You face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): 'Prüfung'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252') returns 'PrÃ¼fung'…

The output encoding is wrong... you're viewing the utf-8 character ü in a 1-byte encoding

@HonkderHase How can I solve this problem? the funny thing is, in some files they are shown propery, and in some not, I have compared every line of code and cannot find the difference in the source codes. Can you point me in the right direction, where I need to look?

@Butch82 it's probably Excel... try to not "open" but "import" the sheet. I know for sure, that Excel can't handle CSV in utf-8 if you only open it.. but if it's imported, it won't display properly.
